# Images don't appear with nuxt generate with target:static, using strapi backend

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi

New to strapi and Nuxt and can't seem to sort this.

I am working on a site to display products for a business. My idea is to locally host Strapi, and use Nuxt to build a fully static site which I can host by manually pushing `/dist` to the hosting site.

Everything is great in development, but when I ran `nuxt generate` and then `nuxt start`, I couldn't see any images for any of the products when the strapi server was not running.

I'm new to web development so thought at first I might have incorrectly assumed I could build a static site this way, but I've been told that it is possible.

I wondered if the problem was that my dynamic pages were not being built at build time, so I added in the generate property in `nuxt.config.js` and used a function to run through the pages. However, this hasn't affected the image problem at all, and I'm not sure I needed to do this.

Do I need to link strapi to aws s3 or another upload provider? I assumed I could probably avoid doing it because I was only running the project locally, but now I'm wondering if that might help.

---

EDIT: the final needed code was as following

```js
// nuxt.config.js
generate: { 
  routes() { 
    return axios.get("localhost:1337/products")
      .then(res => { 
        return res.data.map(product => { 
          return { route: "/products/" + product.id, payload: product }
        })
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: My linked article did not helped? Do you still need to have it running after `nuxt generate` is done? What is the URL fetched in the network tab of the devtools?

Comment: I read through the article and tried the install the starter but there were quite a few errors with dependencies which seem to have stopped me being able to run the site...? Not sure why. I don't need to have strapi running after `nuxt generate` is finished. The url is to localhost:1337 and then the file upload link. The product data and product titles all seem to have been pre-rendered absolutely perfectly. So it's just the images which don't seem to be pre-rendered

Comment: @kissu The error in the console when using `nuxt start` is: 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'. The image links in the network tab all start off as "pending" and then turn to "failed". Not sure if that is useful but just noticed it.

Comment: There may be a way of downloading the images locally during the build or maybe reach to Cloudinary/S3. Not sure how this is done. If I do have some time, I may give it a look and see if it can work with the starter as a local starter.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and see if I can get something to work with aws or cloudinary

Comment: To my memory, there are some "plugins" to Strapi dashboard. And uploading it to Cloudinary could be even better because of the size optimizations and correct format shipped to the end user.

Comment: @kissu cloudinary has helped. My general products page now doesn't make any get requests. However, the child folders (product category pages, and then the individual product pages) continue to make get requests to fetch data. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Maybe missed to reproduce your index's code (`fetch()` hooks or alike) to the children?

Comment: @kissu I've just managed to fix it by adding a function into nuxt.config.js under the generate variable.

Comment: @kissu Hello, can you please outline how did you fix it. My images are not showing up the content and the pages build find. Only images are a problem